# Reverse foreignkey query with peewee

Tags: python, peewee

I'm using the peewee orm and I would like to know how to do a reverse foreignkey query.

These are my models:

```
class Device(BaseModel):
    mac = CharField()
    ip = CharField()

class Metrics(BaseModel):
    device = ForeignKeyField(Device, related_name="metrics")
    sensor = CharField()
    analog = FloatField(null = True)
    timestamp = DateTimeField()
```

I would like to know the simplest way to get all the Devices that have a Metric with a field sensor="temperature".

I can solve it with various querys and some iteration, but I wonder if there is a more direct way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
Device.select().join(Metric).where(Metric.sensor == 'temperature')
```

Another way:

```
Device.select().where(fn.EXISTS(
    Metric.select().where((Metric.sensor == 'temperature') & (Metric.device == Device.id))
))
```

Comment: Thanks. The first option does not work. It just keeps 'thinking' until it gives a timeout error. The second options works perfect, so thank you again. That answer solves me a lot of problems! –